# Vertical centering works for one element but not another

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to position the yellow div vertically and centrally in the green area but it is not working. The structure is exactly the same and work with the mongoDB text so have no idea why it doesn't work.

1. How can I get the yellow div to be vertically centered in the green area?
2. Also I would like the red line (border) between the two texts to be half the size - is there a rule that sets the border height?

Appreciate the help, thanks

```css
#header-title-wrap {
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: #0ff;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
  /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#header-slogan-wrap {
  background: #ff0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#header-text-wrap {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  float: left;
  background: #0f0;
}

#t1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#t1-emphasis {
  color: #2778BA;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700px;
}

#slogan {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-text-wrap">

  <div id="header-title-wrap">
    <span id="t1">mongo<span id="t1-emphasis">DB</span></span>
  </div>

  <div id="header-slogan-wrap">
    <span id="slogan">Slogan text here</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the yellow div to be vertically centered in the green area?

You'll need to set an explicit height to make the layout work in your current code structure.

But since you're already using flexbox on some elements, why not use it on the primary container, as well? This will give you many powerful alignment options and you won't need to set an explicit height.

> Also I would like the red line (border) between the two texts to be half the size - is there a rule that sets the border height?

Instead of a border, consider an absolutely-positioned pseudo-element.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```css
#header-text-wrap {
  display: inline-flex; /* primary flex container */
  background: #0f0;
}

#header-title-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #0ff;
  position: relative; /* sets container for absolutely positioned pseudo element */
}

#header-title-wrap::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

#header-slogan-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  background: #ff0;
}

#t1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#t1-emphasis {
  color: #2778BA;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700px;
}

#slogan {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-text-wrap">
  <div id="header-title-wrap">
    <span id="t1">mongo<span id="t1-emphasis">DB</span></span>
  </div>
  <div id="header-slogan-wrap">
    <span id="slogan">Slogan text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that your slogan text is centered vertically in the `#header-slogan-wrap` div, but the height on that div is set to auto, so it's only actually as tall at the text.

You need to set `height: 100%` on the `#header-slogan-wrap`, that will throw out your background color though, so give it a transparent background and put the yellow background directly behind the `#slogan`.

You also need to put an explicit height on the containing div, rather than just `auto`.

This should vertically align your text.

I would also suggest taking the margin and padding off `#header-text-wrap`. Give `#header-text-wrap` and `#header-slogan-wrap` `height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px;` - obviously use whatever values suit your design.

Comment: it works if I add an 100% height to #header-slogan-wrap and put an explicit height on the containing div, but I don't want the containing div to be a set height - can it be achieved another way?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) from Css Tricks, there they show the different situations and how solve it. It can be usefull for later.